# Scraping with axios(node) works but fails with requests(python)

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, axios

I'm trying to scrape some data from a webapp. The api will return JSON.

Using Node@8.11.1 with axios@0.18.0 I'm able to scrape the data

```
axios.post(url,
    {'data': {'item': null, 'category': null}},
        {headers: {'Authorization': '123'}}
        )
    .then((data) => {
     }
...
```

But using Python@3.5.2 with Requests@2.18.4 fails. I get Http error 415

```
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'Authorization': '123'})
session.post(url, {"data": {"item": None, "category": None}})
```

And if I add a Content-type header, I get Http error 500

```
session.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'})
```

Why Can I scrape with Node and Axios but cannot with Python and Requests?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
The 500 error was related to the data itself.

It seems that I needed to serialize my data before sending it - using **json.dumps()** and add "Content-Type" to my post headers

```
import json
import requests


session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'Authorization': '123'})
session.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'})

session.post(url, json.dumps({"data": {"item": None, "category": None}}))
```